# BTC Full Node Wallet

Tags: bitcoind

Is it possible to use a BTC full node (running on linux) to query an address and either see all of those address transactions or to get a list of their UTXO's so you can calculate a balance and see how much has been spent? If not, how do sites like BitRef accomplish this task? Simply put in BTC address and it shows all the transactions and the balance of the wallet in just a few seconds? Do they have some sort of DB they leverage in addition to the blockchain?